# How can I prevent user input from smashing the stack?

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory

So I was writing a program that takes user input and stores it into a character array with a length of 10 like this:

```
char str[10];
scanf("%s", str);
```

I wanted to see what would happen when I enter an 11 character string, and I got this:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My questions are this:

Is there a way I can prevent the user from entering more than 10 characters by limiting their input somehow?

Is there a way I can take any amount of characters as the input, but then trim the input down to whatever the first 10 characters are entered?

Lastly, and this isn't entirely related to the previous two questions, can I create a character string that allocates just enough space in the character array for the size of the string at the time the user is giving their input? I'm just starting out in C and am trying to do the best I can to prevent my programs from allocating more memory than it needs. I understand I can just say `char str[255];` and call it a day, but that seems wasteful when the user isn't even going to need that many characters. I imagine a scenario where a program asks the user for their name, but I can't just assume their name is more or less than a certain amount of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier to `scanf` allows you to specify a field width which is the maximum number of characters that can be read.  Your buffer is 10 elements wide, so with the terminating null byte you can read at most 9 characters.  You can then specify this size as follows:

```
scanf("%9s", str);
```

If the user enters more than 9 characters they will be left in the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question you can easily limit the number of input using for or while loop. Like in following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 
    int index; 
    char string[7]; 
    printf("Enter a string : "); 
    for(index = 0 ;index<6;index++){ 
        scanf("%c",&string[index]); 
    } 
    string[index]='\0'; //null terminated 
    puts(string); // string function in c to display a string 
    return 0; 
}
```

This will also trim down your number of input. But as mentioned in other answer : `scanf("%9s", str);`, I think is much better, its just that I came to know about this for the first time.

And for your last question you have to use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I like your answer a lot, but the other answer is much cleaner. Still, I appreciate your solution, and I will also look into dynamic memory allocation. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.